Do offensive abilities require the player to hit with an attack roll?
I have a question about abilities that can be used offensively.
In the Cypher System Rulebook, p. 215, it says

An attack is anything that you do to someone that they don't want you to do. … An attack almost always requires a roll to see if you hit or otherwise affect your target.

Consider an ability like stasis:

Stasis (3 Intellect points): You surround a foe of your size or smaller with scintillating energy, keeping it from moving or acting for one minute, as if frozen solid.

and Gravity Cleave:

Gravity Cleave (3 Intellect points): You can harm a target within short range by rapidly increasing gravity's pull on one portion of the target and decreasing it on another, inflicting 6 points of damage.

Is the intention that you pay the cost and make an attack roll, or do you automatically hit since you had to pay a cost to make the attack?

It still requires a roll
This is under Attack action, p. 199

A less straightforward attack might be
a special ability that stuns a foe with a mental blast. However, it’s handled the same way: the player makes a roll against the opponent’s target number.

Look at the martial artist's Stunning Attack ability, which is an ability to stun the target (i.e. exactly matching the example given)

Stunning Attack (4 Might points). You hit your foe in just the right spot, stunning him so that he loses his next action. This attack inflicts no damage. Action.

It's using the same format as the abilities you cite.
